# How to rename all files in a directory adding a prefix

Tags: linux, loops, rename

I first create 10 digit random number

```
export mask=$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM; let "mask %= 10000000000";
```

This command works well

```
for i in /home/testing/*; do mv "$i" "$mask$i"; done
```

The problem with the above command is that it only works when I am in /home/testing. As soon as I move the script, i get this error

```
mv: cannot move ‘/home/testing/rec001.mp4’ to ‘3960731225/home/testing/rec001.mp4’: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why is this tagged MySQL?!

Comment: Also, in the first version your `$i` should still be an absolute path so there's no reason at all why the current working directory should matter.  It would only make a difference if your first version said `for i in *; ...`

Comment: Then why the error msg?

Comment: Are you sure the first line is actually renaming anything?  If `$mask` is blank it'll fail silently.

Comment: @Alnitak first line is working properly I have checked it already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the `path` from the `filename` **before** you apply the `mask`. For example, to use in a script where the directory is passed as an argument to the script:

```
path="$1"

## Note: this assumes you are exporting mask earlier. If not, set mask here

for i in "${path}"/*; do

    dir="${i%/*}"       # path component
    ffname="${i##*/}"   # filename component

    mv "$i" "${dir}/${mask}${ffname}"

done
```

This will apply `mask` to all files in the given directory, no matter where the directory is.

An example of a script that incorporates this is shown below. You can save this script wherever you like. You can either make it executable `chmod 0755 scriptname` or call it with `bash scriptname`. To use the script, add the path you want to prefix the files in as the **first argument**. E.g `bash scriptname /path/to/files` (or just `scriptname /path/to/files` if you made it executable):

```
#!/bin/bash

# validate input
[ -n "$1" ] || {
    printf "error: insufficient input. Usage: %s /path/to/files\n" "${0//\//}"
    exit 1
}

# validate directory
[ -d "$1" ] || {
    printf "error: directory not found: '%s'\n" "$1"
    exit 1
}

path="$1"

## Note: this assumes you are exporting mask earlier. If not, set mask here

## validate mask set and is 10 chars (added per comment)
[ -n "$mask" -a "${#mask}" -eq 10 ] || {
    printf "error: mask '%s' either unset or not 10 characters\n" "$mask"
    exit 1
}

# move files
for i in "${path}"/*; do

    [ -f "$i" ] || continue  # if not file, skip

    dir="${i%/*}"            # path component
    ffname="${i##*/}"        # full filename component (with .ext)

    mv "$i" "${dir}/${mask}${ffname}"

done
```

Here is a sample of what moves would take place with the script named `prefix.sh` when called on the directory `dat` in the current working directory and when called on `~/tmp` outside the current directory:

**output (mask=3960731225):**

```
$ ./prefix.sh dat

 dat/f1f2.dat   => dat/3960731225f1f2.dat
 dat/field.txt  => dat/3960731225field.txt
 dat/flop.txt   => dat/3960731225flop.txt
 dat/hh.dat     => dat/3960731225hh.dat
 dat/hh1.dat    => dat/3960731225hh1.dat
 dat/hostnm     => dat/3960731225hostnm
 dat/hosts.dat  => dat/3960731225hosts.dat

$ ./prefix.sh ~/tmp

  /home/david/tmp/tcpd.tar.xz      => /home/david/tmp/3960731225tcpd.tar.xz
  /home/david/tmp/tcpdump-capt     => /home/david/tmp/3960731225tcpdump-capt
  /home/david/tmp/tcpdump.new.1000 => /home/david/tmp/3960731225tcpdump.new.1000
  /home/david/tmp/test             => /home/david/tmp/3960731225test
```

Comment: A bit lost. How do i tell it to rename /home/testing/* if my script is in /home?

Comment: Sorry, you need some way to pass the path to the loop. You can either hard-code it (not very useful) or pass the path as an argument to the script. You then call `script /path/to/files/to/mv` (note no trailing `/`). I'll drop a full example.

Comment: This seems to be working well but for some reason mask, sometimes is only 9 digits ling and then it messes up all my files. Any clue why this would happen?

Comment: Hmm.., `Note: this assumes you are exporting mask earlier.` I need to know how/when you are setting `mask`. The script takes whatever it is set to and just uses it. We can add a `validation` to check `[ "${#mask}" -eq 10 ]` to insure the mask is exactly `10` chars. I'll add it, you add **how/where** you are setting `mask` to your questions because there is nothing I do that touches it.

Answer (score 1):

There is two commands that is quite helpful, basename and dirname.
They will give you the dir part and the filename, have a look at this test script.

```
#!/bin/bash

mask=$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM; let "mask %= 10000000000";
echo $mask

mkdir -p testing
> testing/nisse.txt
> testing/guste.txt
> testing/berra.txt

ls testing/

for i in testing/*
do 
    file=$(basename $i)
    dir=$(dirname $i)
    newfile=$mask$file
    echo $i $dir $file $newfile

    mv "$dir/$file" "$dir/$newfile"
done

ls testing/
```

And it will output:

```
247639260
berra.txt  gusten.txt  nisse.txt
testing/berra.txt testing berra.txt 247639260berra.txt
testing/guste.txt testing guste.txt 247639260guste.txt
testing/nisse.txt testing nisse.txt 247639260nisse.txt
247639260berra.txt  247639260guste.txt  247639260nisse.txt
```

Please note that I wrote it very verbose to make it more clear and readable.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a `cd` command before your command now, wherever you want to move the script it works,

```
cd /home/testing

for i in /home/testing/*; do mv "$i" "$mask$i"; done
```

Comment: @Andy check my answer, I'm certain the problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks but, its not working. it makes $i a path like filename